# Got "Transaction was not mined within 50 blocks, please make sure you transaction was properly sent." while tx is successful

Tags: blockchain, transactions

I just got a weird issue.
I submitted a tx to Alfajores (Celo's testnet). 10-15 seconds after I click confirm in Metamask, the tx was executed successful. However, frontend was still waiting for the tx result, and soon came the error "Transaction was not mined within 50 blocks, please make sure your transaction was properly sent. Be aware that it might still be mined!"

Here's some notes I got:

1. RPC of frontend and Metamask at Alfajores are the same: https://alfajores-forno.celo-testnet.org
2. I saw the tx status was changed to succesfully green in Activity tab in Metamask
3. The tx was successfully executed in the Explorer as well

Does anyone know what can be the root cause and how to mitigate this?
Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Different networks may have different small oddities and Metamask may not understand how some network works. Or then there's simply a general bug in Metamask - who knows.

Comment: Thanks @LauriPeltonen. This was the first time I saw such an issue in 3 years of working with blockchain